# change the font size and margin of R graph

Tags: r

I am experimenting with the `investigate_var_importance` in package of `bartMachine`

```
investigate_var_importance(bart_machine_cv, num_replicates_for_avg = 20)
```

It turns out that the generated graph is so big, especially the text label along with the `x-axis`. The default `[R Graphics: Device 2(Active)` cannot even hold the whole picture. How to change the font size and margin of this plot?

[image]

Comment: A better way to present this kind of chart and much easier to read if you “transpose” the chart.  ( proportion as x-axis and categories y-axis )

Comment: [Like so:](http://d.elmagoasset.com/16PY5)

Comment: Hi hvollmeier, could you let me know how to transpose the chart? Thank you!

Comment: All you have to do is change the axis. If you are using ggplot to create your graphics one example using the diamonds dataset would be: original: `ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar()` the transposed version: `ggplot(diamonds, aes(color, fill=cut)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()` [example](http://d.elmagoasset.com/1g1mp)

Answer (score 0):

margin can be set by `par(mar=c(bottomMargin, left, up, right))`
see par to set that parameter
c(0,0,0,0) will not leave any space. You might not want this, as there wouldn't be any space for the axis.

```
par(oma=c(bottomMargin, left, up, right))
```

sets the outer margins of the plot

if you send the plot to a pdf, you can increase the size of the plot, which will be able to hold the whole plot i.e,
`pdf('nameOfplot.pdf', 20, 6)` ## opens a device, and produces a file much wider than longer
plot whater you want
`dev.off()` ## closes the device you have opened with pdf

if you play with those parameters you might be able to fit your plot